# Check custom LDAP attribute in OpenAM 13

Tags: authentication, ldap, single-sign-on, openam

I'm using OpenAM 13 to provide single-sign-on capabilities to a suite of applications. The authentication itself is provided by LDAP, as there is an existing LDAP store used by other applications outside the scope of this single-sign-on.

A custom attribute called userattrib1 has been added to each users LDAP record. When this attribute is set to 999, the user is not allowed to log onto the single-sign-on, for all other values they are allowed to log on. I realise this is an unusual setup, however this is part of a pre-existing application.

How would I go about configuring OpenAM 13 to support this check? I'd like to avoid performing this check in the end-user applications, as there are several applications I'd have to add the check to.

Answer (score 0):

If LDAP auth module is used you can specify a user search-filter to leverage the custom attribute.

However NOT searchfilters like

```
userattrib1 != 999
```

will typically lead to unindex searches and can not really be used, instead you should check how many distinct 'passing' values you have and then use that in a compound filter like

```
(|(userattrib1=123)(userattrib1=124)(userattrib1=125)(userattrib1=126))
```

potentially you can even 'group' the values to use a substring filter like

```
userattrib1=12*
```

depending on the filter used you need an equality index or/and a substring index configured for attribute *userattrib1*